# Installer installling other project in VS.NET 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have one project named DBSyncInstaller.It has one installer class and seperate classes along with it. I also have another project named MSSQLDBSync.  I use SetUp and Deployment project called Setup3.This Setup will use installer class of DBSyncInstaller.Then it will  deploy exe(Project OutPut)  of MSSQLDBSYNC.

Please let me know what steps should I carry out.

Regards,

Sachin K

Comment: Yes. Marking an answer means you accept it as a solution to your problem. If none of the answers help you, you can try commenting on some of them. Initiating a dialogue with the people that answer to your posts may lead to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding MSSQLDBSync a custom prerequisite to your main installer. To create the prerequisite manifests you can use the [bootstrapper manifest generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg). After generating them, you can add all these files (including the package) in a separate folder in the Visual Studio prerequisites folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\
```

This way you will be able to select the prerequisite in your setup project:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77z6b8tz(VS.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(VS.80).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx

Comment: Hi Cosmin,Thanks for reply.Can you just guide me how to use Bootstrap?

Comment: Here is a tutorial which may help: http://jcrawfor74.wordpress.com/2008/02/27/bootstrap-manifest-generator-how-to-custom-pre-requisites/

Comment: Hi Cosmin.Thanks.That means I need to create two seperate installers for DBSyncInstallers and MSSQLDBSYNC?The Installler Setup project for MSSQLDBSYNC shall be used by Prerequisites from Installer Setup project from DBSyncInstaller thorough BootStrapper.

Comment: I read your post again and I may have misunderstood what you need to do with the files. Does DBSyncInstaller generate multiple files which need to be installed? Or just an installer class which will be used during install?